# ReactDOM.render to insertBefore instead of replace? (with reason for it, CSS adjacent sibling selector)

Tags: reactjs

Currently with React I am doing this:

```
 ReactDOM.render(<HelloMessage name="John" />, mountNode);
```

This replaces the entire contents of `mountNode`, is it possible to make it `insertBefore` instead of replace? I want to insert it as first child.

EDIT - why i need this, simplified case.
My component is a menu, when it is in the open state, it opens and reveals items like a drawer. So I have to give the element after my menu component a box shadow to show that it is over the revealed elements. I do this with this css:

```
.myComponent[data-state=open] + div {
  background-color: red;
}
```

However myComponent has no adjacent siblings, as i replaced the contents of a target elmeent so this fails. So my work around is to, on every render, set the attribute on the parent node:

```
    if (this.refs.myc) {
        this.state.profiles.length > 0 ? this.refs.myc.parentNode.setAttribute('data-state', 'open') : this.refs.myc.parentNode.removeAttribute('data-state'); // my ugly work around, put the data-state attribute on the parentNode of mountNode
    }
```

However this is not efficient, as it is not setting on virtual dom, but every time on the dom. So i wanted to insert my component as the first child in the body, this way my stylesheet will work.

Here is the working fiddle with work around - https://jsfiddle.net/Noitidart/69z2wepo/26319/

Comment: Don't think there's way out the box, have you considered inserting an element before mountNode and then passing that in?

Comment: No it's not possible. Maybe you need structure like this -  https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/26207/

Comment: Why do you actually want to do it? There are many ways to solve the problem, but you need to provide more information about that use case.

Comment: Thanks @jalooc what I am trying to do is when my component is in `data-state=open` in css then I apply a style to the node following it. So `.myComponent[data-state=open] + div { }`. Thats why I want to insert my component as first child. The way I am doing it right now is on mouse over of my component I am doing `setAttribute` to the parent node (`mountNode`) a data-hover attribue, and then making my css be `[data-state] + div {}`

Comment: Dear @Alexander I wrote a fiddle showing why the structure doesnt work and added reasoning to the topic post, can you please see.

Comment: Dear @DominicTobias wrote a fiddle showing why the structure doesnt work and added reasoning to the topic post, can you please see.

Comment: Dear @jalooc I wrote a fiddle showing why the structure doesnt work and added reasoning to the topic post, can you please see.

Comment: Is there any reason you don't maintain all DOM inside one React app, but instead divide it into menu in form of _React app_ and the content tag? If you kept everything in React, like you should, it would be super-easy to maintain the state in the top-level component and pass it as props to either _Menu_ child component or the _Content_ child component. Thus everything is in sync reactively, React takes care for it for you.

Comment: Thanks @jalooc the reason is because I'm using react to make a firefox addon, so i have to inject the my menu component into the main_browser_menu. Otherwise for my websites and stuff I do one huge react component.

Comment: Ohh, that's a bummer. Then I'm not an expert in Firefox addons, but the workaround you invented seems fine to me.

Comment: Thanks man for your reading and giving me some replies :)

Answer (score 3):

Did you solve this? You should definitely be able to mount it in different places

```
const newChildNode = document.createElement('DIV')
newChildNode.id = 'new-child-node'
document.body.insertBefore(newChildNode, document.getElementById('root'))

ReactDOM.render(<App />, newChildNode)
```

Comment: I could not figure out how to replace contents of an existing node. This is a smart way but also appending. +1 though.